# Error pushing to AWS - Source bundle exceeds maximum allowed size: 524288000

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to host a few sites off a single amazon linux elastic beanstalk micro-instance using AWS. i have one git repo that hosts all the sites. but when i add the last site to the local repo and try to push it i get this error: "Source bundle exceeds maximum allowed size: 524288000"

I have tried breaking it up into multiple pushes but I have read that when you do a git push all the files in the repo are uploaded, not just the changes, and thus trying to add files one at a time wouldn't even work because ultimately if the size of the repo is bigger than the limit i would never be able to push it.

is this true that git uploads the whole repo every single time rather than just the changes, and if so, how am i to resolve this issue? this has been posted a few times on the web since at least 2012 but i haven't seen any answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the folders were simply too big so I added certain ones to my .gitignore

Comment: how did you fix this issue?

Comment: by adding certain large folders to the .gitignore file I was able to reduce the size of the bundle to be uploaded

Comment: genius solution!

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue as well, and thought that I'd share the fix for posterity.

Jenkins pipeline execting NPM build of Nuxt application had a Gulp build (with cleanup) that wasn't sufficiently doing its job. The workspace was accumulating extra cruft, and the option to "Delete workspace before build starts" resolved the issue, bringing build size down from 504M to 111M.

Comment: how do i do this when i am using the UI?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77394609/ui-source-bundle-is-empty-or-exceeds-maximum-allowed-size-524288000

Comment: @x89 go to configure the specific build
Under "Build Environment" section there is a checkbox for "Delete workspace before build starts" and you just check that before saving the configuration.